# How can I control record insertion on button click event in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

I have a button, on popup form, with action method action_replace(). Inside action_replace() there is a logic to replace products in BOM. The model is product.template.

Whenever I click button, a new record is inserted in product_template table. Moreover, a field in my view, default_code, (from product_product table) got updated as well with empty string (since product_template_id linked to product id does not exist in product_product table).

What I have learned is that whenever a button is clicked, the default behaviour of the system is to save the data first and then to execute the button click function. Is there a way to avoid these records insertions?

Answer (score 0):

A button click does nothing *per se*. The code in the function attached to the button is the one that is inserting those records.

To have a different behaviour when clicking on the button you should override the `action_replace()` function.

Comment: Daniel, what I have learned is that whenever a button is clicked, the default behaviour of the system is to save the data first and then to execute the button click function. Please comment on this.

Comment: As a test I made my action_replace() function does nothing and still whenever I click button a record got inserted in product_template table.

Comment: My button function definition is "def action_replace(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):". The ids returns id of the newly inserted record in product_template table.